# View Single Commit History

Tags: git, gerrit, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a way to view the history of a single commit that has been amended multiple times? I am using gerrit, which shows the list of amended commits as patch sets. I would use gerrit to view the changes, but I am working out a conflict such that I can't push my changes to gerrit at the moment so I need something local.

Comment: The best you could do would be to search for all commits with a common parent, and manually filter them down to the commits you suspect are earlier versions of your current commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, that is impossible. Amending a commit [rewrites history](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-commit--amend) (emphasis mine):

> But, **amending doesn’t just alter the most recent commit—*it replaces it entirely***. To Git, it will look like a brand new commit, which is visualized with an asterisk (*) in the diagram above. It’s important to keep this in mind when working with public repositories.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. So gerrit will only show the changes between pushes. Gerrit will not show patch sets between amends.